# C++ Verify if string 1 exist in string 2

Tags: c++, string

Help me please !!

it doesn't work and i didn't founf  the mistake !?

there is a function to verify existence of strings in each other ? 
Thank You !!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
string mot1="abc";
string mot2="oooooabcooo";
int j=1;
while((j!=mot1.length())||(j!=0))
{
    for(int i=0;i<=mot.length();i++)
    {
        if(mot1[i]==mot2[i])
            {j++;}
            else j=0;
    }

}
if(j==mot1.length())
    cout<<mot1<<" existe dans "<<mot2<<endl;
    else

            if(j=0)
        cout<<"erreur";
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the function you are looking for.

```
mot2.find(mot1); // also std::find
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: `std::find` looks for one element, not an entire subsequence. The general algorithm would be [`std::search`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/search) (which can also take a searcher like Boyer-Moore).

Comment: @chris std::find finds the first occurrence of the string in the second string which is what Omar needs

Comment: [It's a single element](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find). To be clear, this just affects the comment in the code, not the string-based find.

Answer (score 0):

There are out of box tools for this, but if you look for a labor coding, I understand nothing from your code. Instead, I find it this way:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int find(string mot1,string mot2)
{
    bool found;
    for(int j=0;j<mot2.length()-mot1.length()+1;j++)
    {
        found=true;
        cout<<"comparing "<<mot1.c_str()<<" and "<<(mot2.c_str()+j)<<endl;
        for(int i=0;i<mot1.length();i++)
            if(mot1[i]!=mot2[i+j])
            {
                found=false;
                break;
            }
        if(found)
            return j;
    }
    return -1;
}

int main()
{
    string mot1="abc";
    string mot2="oooooabcooo";
    cout<<find(mot1,mot2)<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```